# Uploadify: totalBytesTotal not being updated after file removed from the queue

Tags: jquery, uploadify

using latest **jQuery** and **Uploadify** I implemented a single progress bar using **onUploadProgress** which works fine. only problem is that when a file is removed from the queue during upload totalBytesTotal doesn't update itself which makes my progress bar display incorrect information.

suggestions, workarounds welcome.

btw: tried their forum (spam heaven, btw) it seems nobody had such issue.

```
$("#button_holder").uploadify({
    "onUploadProgress" : function(file, bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, totalBytesUploaded, totalBytesTotal){
        pos = Math.round((totalBytesUploaded/totalBytesTotal)*100);
        kb = (totalBytesTotal /1024).toFixed(1);
        $("#progress_text").html("uploading "+ TotalFiles +" files.<br>"+ pos +"% of "+ kb +"kB done.<br>please wait.");
        $("#progress_bar").animate({"width" : pos +"%"},100);
    }
});
```

Comment: It is a hell of spam heaven isn't it! Can you post what code you have put up already, or maybe put it in jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

for anyone having this issue, the trick that worked for me was to use **`onSelect`** and **`onUploadError`** to manage a custom var (in my case *`MyBytesTotal`*) with the total of size of files in the queue and rely on this var instead of **`totalBytesTotal`** in **`onUploadProgress`**.

```
$("#button_holder").uploadify({
    "onSelect" : function(file){
        MyFilesTotal++;
        MyBytesTotal = MyBytesTotal + file.size;
    },
    "onUploadProgress" : function(file, bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, totalBytesUploaded, totalBytesTotal){
        pos = Math.round((totalBytesUploaded/MyBytesTotal)*100);
        kb = (MyBytesTotal /1024).toFixed(1);
        $("#progress_text").html("uploading "+ MyFilesTotal +" files.<br>"+ pos +"% of "+ kb +"kB done.<br>please wait.");
        $("#progress_bar").animate({"width" : pos +"%"},100);
    },
    "onUploadError" : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString){
        MyFilesTotal--;
        MyBytesTotal = MyBytesTotal - file.size;
    }
});
```

I ended up not using the `MyFilesTotal`. no matter what I did it just wouldn't keep the correct amount of files in the queue after some of them had been removed. perhaps there's another way to get this information that I'm not aware of.